# Why workbox and vue doesn't serve the files from the cache?

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

My case is pretty simple. I want to display a custom offline page when I refresh the page and I do not have network connection.

So I create a vue application using the cli with workbox pwa.

This is how vue.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      swSrc: 'public/service-worker.js',
      swDest: 'service-worker.js',
    }
  }
};
```

I add this content to `public/offline.html`:

```
<html>I'm the offline page</html>
```

In the `public/service-worker.js` I do have this code:

```
// public/service-worker.js

const offlinePage = '/offline.html';
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true
});

workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({ prefix: 'my-app' });

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

const customHandler = async args => {
  console.log('in customHandler!!1 route');
  return (await caches.match(offlinePage));
};

workbox.routing.registerRoute('/', customHandler);

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

And run this command:

```
npm run build &&  http-server -p 3001 dist
```

Now, I go to the browser to localhost:3001 and the app is up: `Service worker has been registered.`

Also I see the `/offline` page is cached.

[image]

The problem is when I switch on "Offline" checkbox, and refresh.

I got 404. and not the offline page.

[image]

And The weirdest thing is that **I have nothing in the cache storage**.

[image]

Don't know why it happends. how to serve offline page on lost network connection?

Answer (score 0):

I found some error from your code after I try to reproduce.

> The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:3001/" resulted in a network
>   error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to
>   respondWith().

This must mean something wrong with your return statement:

```js
return (await caches.match(offlinePage))
```

And I found more weird behaviors. When I try to reload, the page will be crashed same as offline. This mean your handler code is also wrong.

```js
const customHandler = async args => {
  console.log('in customHandler!!1 route');
  return (await caches.match(offlinePage));
};

workbox.routing.registerRoute('/', customHandler);
```

From your code it means: I don't care I'm online or offline I will return cached.

I'm not much familiar with workbox but I try to fix that error based on this [Cache.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match):

```js
const customHandler = async args => {
  try {
    // try to load the index.html first
    return await fetch(args.event.request)
  } catch {
    // get cache name since it auto-generated from workbox
    let cache = await caches.open(workbox.core.cacheNames.precache)

    // get url name this can't just be '/offline' since workbox add some auto-generated name
    let url = workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL(offlinePage)

    return caches.match(url)
  }
};
```